# here is my question about why this proxy isn't working as normal?

Tags: python-3.x, https, proxy

This proxy used to work a couple years back when i was doing web development but now it isn't and i can't wrap my head around why. It was designed to see how client side code could be modified and how i should go about securing it. My main issue is that when i run it, and set firefox to use the proxy settings for both http and https, I get connection timeout issues.

Here is my code:

```
# Importing necessary modules
import socket  # Socket programming
import re  # Regular expressions for string manipulation
import datetime  # Date and time manipulation
from cryptography import x509  # X.509 certificate manipulation
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID  # Object identifiers for X.509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes  # Cryptographic hash functions
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa  # RSA encryption
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend  # Cryptography backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization  # Serialization of cryptographic objects
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer  # HTTP server implementation
import ssl  # SSL/TLS functionality

# Defining a class for the proxy server, which extends the BaseHTTPRequestHandler class
class ProxyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
    # Initialize instance variables
    self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0'  # User agent string
    self.modify_request = False  # Flag to indicate if request modification is required
    self.verbose = True  # Flag to enable verbose logging
    self.proxy_host = 'localhost'  # Proxy server host
    self.proxy_port = 8000  # Proxy server port
    self.intercepted_destinations = []  # List of intercepted destinations
    self.intercepted_destinations = [str(dest) for dest in self.intercepted_destinations]  # Convert destinations to strings
    self.proxy_socket = None  # Socket for proxy server connection
    self.ssl_context = None  # SSL context for secure connections

    super().__init__(request, client_address, server)

def log_message(self, format, *args):
    # Override log_message method to customize logging behavior
    if self.verbose:
        super().log_message(format, *args)

def connect_to_proxy(self):
    # Method to connect to the proxy server and generate a self-signed SSL certificate for the server

    # Generating a private key
    private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    # Creating a subject for the certificate
    subject = x509.Name([
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, self.proxy_host)
    ])

    # Building the certificate
    certificate = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
        subject
    ).issuer_name(
        subject
    ).public_key(
        private_key.public_key()
    ).serial_number(
        x509.random_serial_number()
    ).not_valid_before(
        datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    ).not_valid_after(
        datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
    ).add_extension(
        x509.SubjectAlternativeName([x509.DNSName(self.proxy_host)]),
        critical=False
    ).sign(private_key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())

    cert_file = 'proxy_certificate.crt'  # Certificate file name
    key_file = 'proxy_private_key.key'  # Private key file name

    # Saving the certificate to a file
    with open(cert_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(certificate.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM))

    # Saving the private key to a file
    with open(key_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(private_key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
        ))

    # Creating the SSL context for the proxy server
    self.ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    self.ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=cert_file, keyfile=key_file)

    # Creating a socket and connecting to the proxy server
    self.proxy_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.proxy_socket.connect((self.proxy_host, self.proxy_port))

def handle_one_request(self):
    # Method to handle a single request from the client

    # Connect to the proxy server
    self.connect_to_proxy()

    request_data = b''
    while True:
        # Receive request data from the client
        data = self.request.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        request_data += data

    # Split the request into lines
    request_lines = request_data.decode().split('\r\n')
    request_line = request_lines[0]
    method, path, _ = request_line.split(' ')

    headers = {}
    for line in request_lines[1:]:
        # Parse the headers
        if line:
            key, value = line.split(': ')
            headers[key] = value

    body = None
    if '\r\n\r\n' in request_data.decode():
        _, body = request_data.decode().split('\r\n\r\n', 1)

    if self.modify_request:
        # Modify the request content if required
        body = self.modify_request_content(body)

    # Build the modified request
    modified_request = f"{method} {path} HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    modified_request += '\r\n'.join([f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in headers.items()])
    modified_request += '\r\n\r\n'
    if body:
        modified_request += body

    # Send the modified request to the proxy server
    self.proxy_socket.sendall(modified_request.encode())

    response = b''
    try:
        while True:
            # Receive response data from the proxy server
            data = self.proxy_socket.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            response += data
    except ConnectionResetError:
        pass

    # Send the response back to the client
    self.request.sendall(response)

def modify_request_content(self, request):
    # Method to modify the request content

    print("Intercepted packet:")
    print(request)

    # Perform content modification (replace tags with "REPLACED")
    modified_request = re.sub(r'<.*?>', 'REPLACED', request)

    for destination in self.intercepted_destinations:
        # Check if the request contains intercepted destinations
        if self.request_contains_destination(request, destination):
            # Remove the destination from the intercepted list if found
            self.intercepted_destinations.remove(destination)
            self.modify_request = False
            break

    return modified_request

def request_contains_destination(self, request_path, destinations):
    # Check if the request path contains any of the intercepted destinations
    for destination in destinations:
        if destination.encode() in request_path.encode():
            return True
    return False

def do_CONNECT(self):
    # Handler method for the CONNECT request method

    self.send_response(200, 'Connection established')
    self.send_header('User-Agent', self.user_agent)
    self.end_headers()
    self.log_message('CONNECT %s %s', self.path, self.protocol_version)

    self.request.sendall(b'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n')

    # Create SSL context for the client-side connection
    self.ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    self.ssl_context.check_hostname = False
    self.ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

    # Wrap the request socket with the SSL context
    self.request = self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(self.request, server_side=True)

    try:
        # Create a socket and connect to the destination server
        self.proxy_socket = socket.create_connection((self.path, 443))
        # Wrap the proxy socket with the SSL context
        self.proxy_socket = self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(
            self.proxy_socket,
            server_hostname=self.path,
        )
    except socket.error as e:
        self.log_error('Failed to connect to the destination server: %s', str(e))
        return

    self.forward_data()

def forward_data(self):
    # Method to forward data between the client and the destination server

    try:
        while True:
            # Forward data from the client to the destination server
            data = self.request.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            self.proxy_socket.sendall(data)

            # Forward data from the destination server to the client
            response = self.proxy_socket.recv(4096)
            if not response:
                break
            self.request.sendall(response)
    except Exception as e:
        self.log_error('Error during data forwarding: %s', str(e))
    finally:
        # Close the connections
        self.request.close()
        self.proxy_socket.close()

def do_GET(self):
    # Handler method for the GET request method

    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.send_header('User-Agent', self.user_agent)
    self.end_headers()
    self.log_message('GET %s %s', self.path, self.protocol_version)

    # Handle the request
    self.handle_one_request()

def do_POST(self):
    # Handler method for the POST request method

    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.send_header('User-Agent', self.user_agent)
    self.end_headers()
    self.log_message('POST %s %s', self.path, self.protocol_version)

    # Handle the request
    self.handle_one_request()


def main():
# Main function

proxy_host = 'localhost'  # Proxy server host
proxy_port = 8000  # Proxy server port

try:
    # Create and start the HTTP server with the proxy handler
    server = HTTPServer((proxy_host, proxy_port), ProxyServer)
    print(f"Proxy server started on {proxy_host}:{proxy_port}")
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Proxy server stopped")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does it work with plain HTTP sites like `http://neverssl.com`?

Comment: It doesn't, it just sits there loading the website. I'm using 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux, and my python version is 3.9.